# Why I am getting this error while doing Method Cascade in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a single line code which removes trailing and leading whitespaces, and also replaces multiple spaces in between with a single space. (from a string)

```dart
value = value..trim()..split(" +")..join(" ");
```

However I am getting the following error.

```
The method 'join' isn't defined for the type 'String'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'join'.(dartundefined_method)
```

What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot adding RegExp.

```dart
value = value.trim().split(RegExp(" +")).join(" ");
```

is working!!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need cascade notation there:

```dart
value = value.split(' ').where((x) => x.isNotEmpty).map((x) => x.trim()).join(" ")
```

Comment: Yay!! error has been resolved. One more question it is not replacing multiplespaces in between with a single space.

Comment: You mean "abc<space><space><space><space>xyz" -> "abc+xyz", right?

Comment: No! I mean "abc<space><space><space><space>xyz" -> "abc<space>xyz"

Comment: I see, I've updated the answer that should work as you expect

Comment: I just found the bug, I wasn't using RegEx, `value = value.trim().split(RegExp(" +")).join(" ");` is working. Thank you for help.